# pl/sql to get end date from start date

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger to get value of `validity` from `plan` table and add it to the value of `startdate` to get the `enddate` into `dblog` table.I have written this trigger.

My `dblog` and `plan` table schema is like this

```
desc dblog;
 Name                         Null?    Type
 ---------------------------- -------- -------
 PLANID                       NOT NULL NUMBER
 STARTDATE                             DATE
 ENDDATE                      NOT NULL DATE

desc plan;
 Name                         Null?    Type
 ---------------------------- -------- -------
 PLANID                       NOT NULL NUMBER
 VALIDITY                     NOT NULL NUMBER
```

By default column `STARTDATE` has `SYSDATE` value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg2
BEFORE INSERT ON dblog FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_startdate date :=  SYSDATE;
   l_enddate date;
   l_validity number;
BEGIN
 SELECT validity INTO l_validity
   FROM plan
  WHERE planid = :NEW.planid;

 l_endate := l_startdate + l_validity;

 SET :NEW.enddate := l_enddate;

END;
/
```

it shows following error:

```
10/2     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/6     PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Am I using wrong concept or what? How can i get this done?

Comment: Hi can i ask where will you get the :new.planid?

Comment: Where is the Insert to table `dblog` being executed? It wouldn't by any chance be from the Insert trigger of table `plan`, would it?

Answer (score 3):

> l_startdate SYSDATE;

You have not declared the **data type** of the variable, **SYSDATE** is an inbuilt function and not a data type.

If you want to assign the value at the time of data type declaration, then do it as:

```
DECLARE
   l_startdate DATE := SYSDATE;
```

For example,

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    start_dt DATE := SYSDATE;
  3  BEGIN
  4    dbms_output.put_line(start_dt);
  5  END;
  6  /
29-SEP-15

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**UPDATE** OP edited the question

The below query will fail:

```
SELECT validity INTO l_validity from plan where planid=:new.planid;
```

since your trigger is defined on `dblog` table, however, you are referring to the :new values for `plan` table.

Also,

```
SET :NEW.enddate := l_enddate;
```

You don't need the **SET** clause, simply do it as:

```
:NEW.enddate := l_enddate;
```